# PHP Syntax error on MyISAM > InnoDB: expecting '}'

Tags: php, mysql, converters, innodb, myisam

When executing a script [I found online](https://pantheon.io/blog/moving-mysql-tables-myisam-innodb) that someone created to convert MyISAM to InnoDB it throws a syntax error that I've tried to figure out and put in randomly (Not this in depth of a PHP programmer at all.) Someone kindly help a python programmer?

```
[root@server~]# php cli-mysql-to-innodb.php 
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting '}' in /root/cli-mysql-to-innodb.php on line 44
```

**Lines 40-53**:

```
 40 while ($row= $results->fetch_assoc()) {
 41         $sql = "SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = '{$row['Tables_in_' . $db['database']]'";
 42         $thisTable = $mysqli->query($sql)->fetch_assoc();
 43 
 44          if ($thisTable['Engine']==='MyISAM') {
 45                 $sql = "alter table " . $row['Tables_in_' . $db['database']]. " ENGINE = InnoDB;";
 46                 echo "Changing {$row['Tables_in_' . $db['database']]} from {$thisTable['Engine']} to InnoDB.\n";
 47                 $mysqli->query($sql);}
 48         } else {
 49                 echo $row['Tables_in_' . $db['database']] . ' is of the Engine Type ' . $thisTable['Engine'] . ".\n";
 50                 echo "Not changing to InnoDB.\n\n";
 51         }
 52 }
 53
```

**Overall Script**

```
<?php
/*
 * Use this version if you are NOT a Pantheon customer. 
 */
$db = array();

/*
 * Change these to match your database connection information
 */
$db['host']     = "localhost";
$db['port']     = "3306";
$db['user']     = "";
$db['password'] = "";
$db['database'] = "";

/*
 * DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE
 * Unless you know what you are doing. :)
 */
$db['connectString'] = $db['host'];

if (isset($db['port']) && (int)$db['port']==$db['port']) {
    $db['connectString'] .= ":" . $db['port'];
}

$mysqli = @new mysqli($db['connectString'], $db['user'], $db['password'], $db['database']);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error ."\n";
    die(1);
}

$results = $mysqli->query("show tables;");

if ($results===false or $mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "MySQL error: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error ."\n";
    die(2);
}

while ($row= $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $sql = "SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = '{$row['Tables_in_' . $db['database']]'";
    $thisTable = $mysqli->query($sql)->fetch_assoc();

    if ($thisTable['Engine']==='MyISAM') {
        $sql = "alter table " . $row['Tables_in_' . $db['database']]. " ENGINE = InnoDB;";
        echo "Changing {$row['Tables_in_' . $db['database']]} from {$thisTable['Engine']} to InnoDB.\n";
        $mysqli->query($sql);       
    } else {
        echo $row['Tables_in_' . $db['database']] . ' is of the Engine Type ' . $thisTable['Engine'] . ".\n";
        echo "Not changing to InnoDB.\n\n"; 
    }
}

die(0);
```

Comment: I wonder how you didn't notice that you it missed the `}` as it clearly says it is expecting something !!

Comment: Because it also said line 44! Not line 41? I'm use to the luxery of python errors not php.

Comment: Anyways even if you copy & paste the code, i recommend you to have at-least a minimal level of debugging

Comment: Things that should be changed during the conversion:  [Blog on MyISAM to InnoDB](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't  close brace in this line 41,

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = '{$row['Tables_in_' . $db['database']]'";
```

try like this

```
 $sql = "SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = '{$row['Tables_in_' . $db['database']]}'";
```